# Какие название у папок у почты и как к ним обратится в imbox python?

Tags: python, email, imap

Документация https://github.com/martinrusev/imbox упрощающая библиотека для работы imaplib

```
# pip install icecream

import folder as folder

from icecream import ic

from imbox import Imbox

print = ic

with Imbox('imap.yandex.ru',
    username='',
    password='',
    ssl=True,
    ssl_context=None,
    starttls=False) as imbox:

    # В данном коде пытаюсь просто обратится к элементу списка папок 
    # полученных через inbox с помощью функции приведенной в их документации.

    # Get all folders
    status, folders_with_additional_info = imbox.folders()

    folders = folders_with_additional_info
    print(folders)


    # Messages from a specific folder
    messages_in_folder_social = imbox.messages(folder=folders[0]) # Вот здесь обращаюсь к элементу списка. так понимаю это надо делать как то по другому. то ли по названию, но какие у них названия так и не понял. на почте в браузере кириллицей просто "сентябрь" например написано, но на такую строку тоже ругается.



    for uid, message in messages_in_folder_social:
        fromm = message.sent_from
        print(fromm)
```

Пытаюсь получить названия папок почты. но принтует он мне их в каком то странном виде. пробовал декодировать думал на кириллицу ругается, не помогло. Part of print(folders):

```
ic| main.py:18 in <module>
folders: [b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Unmarked \\Sent) "|" "&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-'
          b'"',
          b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Unmarked) "|" "&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD4- &BDgENw- 1'
          b'&BCE-"',
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Константин Петров\Google Диск\MAIL\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    messages_in_folder_social = imbox.messages(folder=folders[0])
  File "C:\Users\Константин Петров\Google Диск\MAIL\venv\lib\site-packages\imbox\imbox.py", line 91, in messages
    self.connection.select(
  File "C:\Users\Константин Петров\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 756, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "C:\Users\Константин Петров\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\Константин Петров\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 1055, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'Command syntax error. sc=ETJkLt2DpW21_011229_2-a1d8e9165a53']
```

Comment: Сейчас я предполагаю что это связано с кодировкой. Надо попробовать декодировать названия папок по utf-7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достал папки с помощью другой библиотеки
https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

mailbox = MailBox('imap.yandex.ru')
mailbox.login('mail', 'password')

print(mailbox.folder.list())
```